# Can a variable be used in Python to define decimal places

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm familiar with the convention of using `%.2f` to set two decimal places for a float but is it in any way possible to change the number to a variable so that the user can state the number of decimal places displayed?

Answer (score 41):

[`.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) is a nicer, more readable way to handle variable formatting:

```
'{:.{prec}f}'.format(26.034, prec=3)
```

Comment: So can the prec=3 bit be changed to use a variable? prec=length for example?

Comment: I agree new string formatting makes it much better. @KirkRogers Yes it can be

Comment: If you have multiple arguments to format, make sure positional arguments are specified before keyword arguments. Example: `'{0:.{prec}f} {1:.{prec2}f}'.format(26.034, 17/3, prec2=6, prec=3)
'26.034 5.666667'`

Comment: Definition of the format() function: `S.format(*args, **kwargs) -> str`
        
        Return a formatted version of S, using substitutions from args and kwargs.
        The substitutions are identified by braces ('{' and '}').

Answer (score 19):

For Python 3.6+ you can do this with f-string style formatter:

```
num = 0.123456789
precision = 3
print(f"{num:.{precision}f}")
```

Output:

```
0.123
```

Answer (score 15):

With the older string format operator, you can use `'%.*f' % (decimals, number)`:

```
>>> number = 26.034
>>> '%.*f' % (3, number)
'26.034'
>>> '%.*f' % (2, number)
'26.03'
>>> '%.*f' % (1, number)
'26.0'
```

Comment: Is this just for 2.7? I don't know if what I want to do is even possible. I really am a beginner at Python.

    number=45.8798
    dec=int(input("how many places?")
    '%.*f' % (dec, number)