# Decorator timer function with variable formatting (decimal places)?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a decorator for a timer so that i can easily call `@decoratortimer` for my functions to time the amount of time taken my function took to run.

However, I cant seem to be able to make my decorator function variable such that I can change the number of decimal places as per user request.

```
import time

def decoratortimer(decimal):
    def decoratorfunction(f):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            time1 = time.time()
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            time2 = time.time()
            print('{:s} function took {:{}f} ms'.format(f.__name__, ((time2-time1)*1000.0), decimal ))
            return result
        return wrap
    return decoratorfunction

@decoratortimer(2)
def callablefunction(name):
    print(name)
print(callablefunction('John'))

#outputs "callablefunction function took 1.008511 ms"
```

As you can see from my code, I've formatted my string as such,

```
print('{:s} function took {:{}f} ms'.format(f.__name__, ((time2-time1)*1000.0), decimal ))
```

My expected output is that it is supposed to print out `callablefunction function took 1.01 ms` because i've passed in the integer value of 2 for my decimal places in `@decoratortimer`.

Could I be formatting my string wrongly? I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728321/can-a-variable-be-used-in-python-to-define-decimal-places) and tried to emulate it but still cant get my decorator function to work! Please help, I cant seem to *wrap* my head around this. (No pun intended).

Comment: `'{:s} function took {:.2f} ms'.format(...)`

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks for your comment! I cant believe i overlooked such a minor detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `{:{}f}` with `{:.{}f}` to get the number of decimal places.

Another topic: consider using `time.monotonic` instead of `time.time` for this case. If the system clock gets an update during your function runs, the result may become negative. `time.monotonic` is guaranteed to increase. The values themselves are not relevant, only the difference between them is.
([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic))

Comment: Oh wow, I cant believe i didnt catch that even after staring long enough. Good catch! What is time.monotonic btw? Is it more accurate? How different is it from time.time?

Comment: I see, the documentation did say that it returns in fractional seconds, is there any difference between milliseconds and fractional seconds?

Comment: @Axois fractional second is `1.5`, milliseconds is `1500.` So `time.time() - time.time()` and `time.monotonic() - time.monotonic()` both return the same float in seconds as long as the system clock doesn't get an update. If it gets an update, the `monotonic` version is precise.